# i18n translate text in a function

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I'm having some problem to translate some error message outside a components.

this is my i18n setting

```
const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: (cb: (baseLanguage: string) => void) => {
    let prevLanguage: string;
    store.subscribe(() => {
      const selectBaseLanguage = makeSelectBaseLanguage();
      const baseLanguage = selectBaseLanguage(store.getState());
      if (baseLanguage !== prevLanguage) {
        prevLanguage = baseLanguage;
        cb(baseLanguage);
      }
    });
  },
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    debug: true,
    resources: languagesResources,
    // language to use if translations in user language are not available.
    fallbackLng: defaultLanguage,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },

    react: {
      wait: false,
      useSuspense: false,
    },
  });
```

i've to reach the errors code in this file ----> `httpErrors: en_HttpError`

path file : `@config/locales/languageConfig`

```
export const languagesResources = {
  en: { ...en, httpErrors: en_HttpError },
  tr: { ...tr, httpErrors: tr_HttpError },
};
```

and this is the `function*` where i need to reach the traduction:

path file : `@config/utils/helpers`

```
export function* _handleFetchError(error: any) {
  const { httpStatus, httpDescriptions, errorCode, errorDescription } = error;
  console.log('!!! Start Error Handler !!!:', httpStatus, httpDescriptions, errorCode, errorDescription);

  const test = i18n.t('en_HttpError');

  yield put(sagaShowFullScreenOverlay(GenericOverlay, errorModal));
}
```

right now with the `const test` i obtain only an undefined error,

How can i obtain the right traduction based on the errorCode value that I receive without have an undefined error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would need more info about your error, but you maybe want to do something like that:
[i18next Fallback](https://www.i18next.com/principles/fallback#:%7E:text=error.unspecific).
So you can show a message that depends of httpStatus response like `error.404` as `Página no encontrada`

Considerate your i18n.t function waits a text key for a registered translation.

In my simple case:

```
i18n.init({
    fallbackLng: {
        default: ['es'],
    },
    resources: {
        es: {
            common: {
                Name: 'Nombre',
....
```

Then, I can do `i18n.t('Name')` for get `'Nombre'`